# WHERE in SQL only allowing 1 clause

Tags: sql

I am getting an error

> Msg 102
>   Incorrect syntax near ' , ' -

after I add any `WHERE` criteria after

```
o.Status = 'Open'
```

The query will run if I take `MAXReceiveDate, MAXDateEnt, o.PartNo` out of the `WHERE` clause, but I need that criteria.

```
DECLARE @now DATETIME
DECLARE @90daysago DATETIME

SET @now = GETDATE()
SET @90daysago = DATEADD(day, -90, @now)

SELECT
    MAX(r.ReceiveDate) AS MaxReceiveDate,
    MAX(po.DateEnt) AS MaxDateEnt,
    MAX(po.PONum) AS MaxPONum,
    o.JobNo, o.PartNo, o.Status
FROM 
    OrderDet as o
INNER JOIN 
    PODet as pod ON o.PartNo = pod.PartNo
INNER JOIN 
    Receiver as r ON pod.PONum = r.POnum
INNER JOIN 
    PO as po ON pod.PONum = po.PONum
WHERE
    o.Status = 'Open',
    MAXReceiveDate <= @90daysago,
    MAXDateEnt <= @90daysago,
    PartNo = '72347'
GROUP BY 
    o.PartNo, o.JobNo, o.Status
```

Comment: Which RDBMS is this for? Please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As previous comment said, you can't use the aggregate alias in the WHERE clause. You'll need a HAVING to do what you're trying to do. Try something like:

```
DECLARE @now DATETIME
DECLARE @90daysago DATETIME

SET @now = GETDATE()
SET @90daysago = DATEADD(day, -90, @now)

SELECT
      MAX(r.ReceiveDate) AS MaxReceiveDate
    , MAX(po.DateEnt) AS MaxDateEnt
    , MAX(po.PONum) AS MaxPONum
    , o.JobNo
    , o.PartNo
    , o.[Status]
FROM OrderDet as o
INNER JOIN PODet as pod
    ON o.PartNo = pod.PartNo
INNER JOIN Receiver as r
    ON pod.PONum = r.POnum

INNER JOIN PO as po
    ON pod.PONum = po.PONum
WHERE
    o.Status = 'Open'
    AND o.PartNo = '72347'
GROUP BY o.PartNo, o.JobNo, o.[Status]
HAVING 
    MAX(r.ReceiveDate) <= @90daysago
    AND MAX(po.DateEnt) <= @90DaysAgo
```

Answer (score 7):

You have to concatenate WHERE clauses with `AND`, not `,`:

```
WHERE
    o.Status = 'Open'
    AND MAXReceiveDate <= @90daysago
    AND MAXDateEnt <= @90daysago
    AND PartNo = '72347'
```

Comment: Wow, those are the errors I make when I write queries for 8 hours. I feel so dumb. Thank you!

Comment: We've all been there. ;)

Comment: Well, I am new to the whole SQL thing. Now I realize I can't call to the aggregate values from my select statement. Any direction for fixing that?

Comment: Don't use the alias in your WHERE clause. repeat the aggregate. WHERE MAX(r.ReceivedDate) <= @90daysago

Comment: You may need to use HAVING instead of WHERE, depending on the behaviour you want.

Comment: Keep in mind the basic order of operations of a SQL statement: FROM  >>  WHERE >> GROUP BY  >> HAVING >> SELECT >> ORDER BY >> TOP

Comment: Since when can you have an aggregate in a `Where` clause? Assuming this is SQL Server.

Comment: Following steps will have access to things created in the previous steps. So you won't be able to use Aliases defined in the SELECT until very late in the process.